# How can I scrape my sock-shop metrics with prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-operator

I am currently running my sock-shop app in a sock-shop namespace and my Prometheus is running on default. I downloaded the prometheus with helm from this repo `prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack`.

My prometheus service works just fine and it can scrape its data, but I have been stuck with prometheus scraping my sock-shop metrics. I can see my sock-app running with this AWS Loadbalance `a2417470ff04a4e7f9cdc10555366465-686477968.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`. The metrics of the app can be accessed with `a2417470ff04a4e7f9cdc10555366465-686477968.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/metrics`.

This is what I have done so far, I created values.yaml file with the configuration found in `helm inspect values  prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack`. I added this configuration to the values.yaml file then ran this command
`helm upgrade prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -f values.yaml`

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  evaluation_interval: 5s
rule_files:
  - /etc/prometheus/prometheus.rules
  - /etc/prometheus/alert.rules
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - scheme: http
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - "alertmanager.monitoring.svc:9093"
serverFiles:
  scrape_configs:
    - job_name: prometheus
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['a2417470ff04a4e7f9cdc10555366465-686477968.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/']
    - job_name: "front-end"
      scrape_interval: 5s
      metrics_path: 'metrics'
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod
          namespaces:
            names: [sock-shop]
      relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number]
          action: keep
          regex: '9102'
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['a8c59b00004dc4906809bc261c3b586f-64967486.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com']
```

This is my `prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus` service configuration configuration

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: prometheus
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-14T10:36:24Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app: kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus-stack
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 45.7.1
    chart: kube-prometheus-stack-45.7.1
    heritage: Helm
    release: prometheus
    self-monitor: "true"
  name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "19013"
  uid: 8c59b000-04dc-4906-809b-c261c3b586fc
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 10.100.8.0
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.100.8.0
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http-web
    nodePort: 31906
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus
    prometheus: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: a8c59b00004dc4906809bc261c3b586f-1408557768.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

This is an image of my prometheus url
[image]

Please what am I getting wrong, how can my prometheus start getting my metrics. I am new to prometheus though.

Comment: A drive-by comment, apologies if I misunderstood. To configure the Prometheus Operator, you can use [`PodMonitor`](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/design.md#podmonitor) and [`ServiceMonitor`](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/design.md#servicemonitor) Custom Resources.

Comment: You need to create (either of) these in the namespace where your app is deployed. See [Deploying the sample application](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md#deploying-a-sample-application) where a `ServiceMonitor` is created.